# I have to display separate Array value. how can i do it in android studio

Tags: android, arrays, string, hex, byte

```
         `list.add(new TextItem(ByteUtils.byteArrayToHexString(device.getScanRecord())));`
```

I want to print 3rd record of the getScanRecod.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<String> arrl = new ArrayList<String>();
    //adding elements to the end
    arrl.add("First");
    arrl.add("Second");
    arrl.add("Third");
    arrl.add("Random");
```

To retrive data you can Iterate(Use ForEach Loop) over arrayList or you can do following

```
Iterator<String> itr = arrl.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    list.add(new TextItem(ByteUtils.byteArrayToHexString(device.getScanRecord())))

    .
    .
    .

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
            if(i==3)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"list value "+list.get(i).getRecord());
            }
    }
```